# How can I add webflow using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring-webflow

I have written a Spring web app for baseball umpires using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf. I like Spring Boot because it resolves dependency w/o a lot of configuration. Now I want to add Sprng WebFlow so umpires can order uniforms, a typical "shopping cart" application. There are many examples on the web but none using Spring Boot. They all are the traditional xml config with jsp and jstl. Has anyone used Spring Boot and WebFlow? There are WebFlow examples on the official Spring web site but very complicated. Thanks Rob

Answer (score 0):

Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 generates Spring Boot applications and integrates Spring Web Flow easier than ever.

The [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/) includes detailed descriptions of all the features, plus an extensive user guide for main use cases.